# Change file encoding prigramatically on php

Tags: php, csv

There is any way to change a file csv encoding to utf-8 programmatically on php?Something that makes the same like save as with utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

From what you write it looks to me as if you are looking for a general conversion of file encodings.
Well you can generally read the lines, convert them and write to a new file.

Have a look at [PHP iconv function](http://php.net/manual/de/function.iconv.php)